# Is there a feature selection library in Python for multivariate time series classification dataset?

Tags: time-series, classification, python, feature-selection

I have a multivariate time series (3D) dataset of the shape, *(samples, sequences, features)*. For instance, *(patients, time_sequences_in_hour, features)*, whereby each sample is a distinct group of time sequences. For each sample, there is a binary or multiclass target.

I read through questions such as [Feature selection for time series data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144116/feature-selection-for-time-series-data), but the question covers time series forecasting which libraries like TsFresh can handle. Besides, the feature selection libraries in Python that I have surveyed so far are on tabular (2D) data, i.e: [ReliefF](https://epistasislab.github.io/scikit-rebate/).

Is there a feature selection library in Python that works well for multivariate time series classification dataset as I mentioned above?

Comment: Why do you have to do feature selection at all?